# SQL Server : limitation of 1000 columns per table

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am saving in real-time on a second basis the prices of N different stocks into a Microsoft SQL Server 2012 database where all the data for a specific day go into a specific data table for that day.

As I want to be as quick as possible retrieving the data in real-time, the table structure is as simple as possible: with the row-names marking the time-stamp and the column names the unique names of the stocks. This set-up is simple but useful as it is important to obtain an synchronous snapshot of the data simultaneously when analysing the data.

The problems occurs when the number of stocks N exceeds 1000 as SQL Server  does not allow me to create tables with more than 1000 columns.

My question is how I should best design a database in the case of N > 1000 such that the data-retrieval compromises speed as little as possible and also shifts as little database logic to the user as possible (such as keeping explicitly track of what stock belongs to which table in the case of a multi-table solution).

Any comments would be welcome

Comment: Good question.i recommend posting on dba,se with sample table structure as well for more help and what issues you can get with sample scenarios you have thought

Comment: thank you! Was looking under tags for "dba" that you suggested. Couldn't find anything. Can you help?

Comment: ask here:http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your database design is flawed, you should design your table like this:

```
RecordID
StockID
DateTime
Value
```

and have one row per recorded value per stock and collate afterwards.

Comment: thanks for your comment!  However I am expecting about 20 million rows in this case (instead of 20 000 lines) and I wonder whether this would be seriously slowing down the data-retrieval of a selected group of stocks. Would it not?

Comment: Frankly no, I don't think it would, as long as you are running a database server with suitable hardware and configuration. Once you have this data you will undoubtedly be wanting to run comparisons and reports from it which you will find a lot easier and quicker storing the information like this.